# Configuring stylelint for React Native and styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components, stylelint

I've been trying to set up stylelint to my React Native repo, which uses a mix of `StyleSheet` and `styled-component`s.

With the following configuration

```
{
  "processors": [
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components"
  ],
  "extends": [

    "stylelint-config-styled-components"
  ],
  "plugins": ["stylelint-react-native"],
}
```

I get errors for lines such as `shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 };` in the form of `Missed semicolon   CssSyntaxError`, but I believe my usage of `shadowOffset` is correct.

Things get weirder when I add these to my configuration:

```
  "rules": {
    "react-native/style-property-no-unknown": true,
    "react-native/css-property-no-unknown": true
  }
```

Has anyone made stylelint work correctly with React Native and styled-components?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [stylelint-config-react-native-styled-components](https://github.com/kristerkari/stylelint-config-react-native-styled-components). It's a:

> Shareable stylelint config for styled components when using React Native